# Prove one of the following trajectories is circular

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

In his classical mechanics lecture, Prof Susskind gives a short exercise, which I "feel"  is very simple, but don't know where to start with. The question is:

> "There is a coordinate system $(x,y)$, which is stationary. Another system, $(X,Y)$ with  origin common to the previous one is rotating with a uniform velocity, through an angle $\omega{t}$. The trajectories are(ignoring masses and $t$):
>
> $$\ddot{X}    = {\omega^2}x - \omega\dot{y}$$
>
> $$\ddot{Y} =   \omega^2{y} + \omega \dot{x}$$
>
> Prove that one of the trajectories is circular."

However, both the terms will equal to $0$ because the velocity is constant, and hence the acceleration is zero. Now, what should I do with these? Should I prove $\ddot{x}$ = $\ddot{y}$= $0$, or  something else? Please explain.

Comment: In circular motion, the *speed* is constant, the velocity isn't! Have you ever tried running in a circle? You can feel the acceleration ;)

Comment: You have two coincident coordinate systems and a trajectory. Trajectory _of what_? Is there a point particle here, or something else because as stated the question does not make sense to me.

Comment: I feel you have to use the rate of change of a vector attached to a rotating frame $$\frac{{\rm d}\vec{q}}{{\rm d}t} = \dot{\vec{q}} + \vec{\omega}\times \vec{q}$$

Comment: Prof. Susskind? I had no idea these were on the web: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyX8kQ-JzHI&feature=kp Thanks for alerting the me to them!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the coordinates of a particle with a unit circle trajectory:

$$x(t) = \cos(\omega t)$$

$$y(t) = \sin (\omega t)$$

The velocity of the particle is

$$\mathbf v(t) = \dot x(t)\mathbf i + \dot y(t)\mathbf k = -\omega \sin (\omega t)\mathbf i + \omega \cos (\omega t) \mathbf j$$

which clearly changes with time.

However, the *speed* of the particle

$$v = \sqrt{\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v} = \omega\sqrt{\sin^2(\omega t) + \cos^2(\omega t)} = \omega $$

is *constant*.

This can only be true if the acceleration vector is (always) orthogonal to the velocity vector.